# datePicker : get the TD element object of a DAY

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to be able to find the parent "td" of a day on a datepicker calendar, but can't find a way to do this.

Example of the outpout of a datepicker :

```
<td class=" " data-year="2013" data-month="6" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a>
</td>
```

There is a "data-year", "data-month" but no "data-day".. why ? I don't want to have to fetch each element to find the good one for every day object i want to get.. i should be able to access a day element directly...

The purpose is to add a class to the days i want (like an highlight class for example). I can't use "beforeShowDay"...everyone is talking about this, but it don't work for me since i need to add the class after the page load (example: booking a specific date by ajax and updating the calendar by highlighting the selected days without reloading the whole calendar or page)

I don't want to use "onselect" too, i need to be able to highlight my dates (by adding a class) without this AND be able to do it after the calendar is loaded.

To be more simple, i would like to access a day element like i access a div with

```
$('#divname").css(...)
```

for example. Or a similar way to change directly a day element.

Thanks for the help

Comment: ran into the same problem two years ago. ending up using Keith Woods datepicker: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html - there is at least a class with timestamp and a title with a date format for each cell/day

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just figured out that the calendar refresh itself when you do another jquery ui action (like openning a modal popup) so it solved my problem i just have to use beforeShowDay